# Verification of a proof regarding tangent ratio of sum of $n$ angles

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

It is required to prove that:
$$\tan(A_1+A_2+A_3+..........+A_n)=\frac{s_1-s_3+s_5+......}{1-s_2+s_4+........}.....(1)$$
where $s_r$ denotes the sum of products of tangent ratio of angles taken $r$ at a time out of given $n$ angles.
Proof:(by induction on $n$ or the number of angles)
For $n=2$ we can easily verify the identity.
Let $(1)$ be true for $n=k$. For $n=k+1$, we see that
$$\tan((A_1+.....+A_k)+A_{k+1})=\frac{\tan(A_1+.....+A_k)+\tan(A_{k+1})}{1-\tan(A_1+A_2+....+A_k)\tan(A_{k+1})}......(2)$$
We can expand $\tan((A_1+.....+A_k)$ as in $(1)$(with $s_r$ retaining its meaning) like:
$$\tan((A_1+.....+A_k)=\frac{s_1-s_3+s_5+......}{1-s_2+s_4+........}$$ and replace in $(2)$ to get:  $$\tan(A_1+.....+A_k+A_{k+1})=\frac{s_1-s_3+s_5+......+\tan(A_{k+1})(1-s_2+s_4+........)}{1-s_2+s_4+........-\tan(A_{k+1})(s_1-s_3+s_5+........)}$$
Evidently,This expression at the end would reduce to the form in $(1)$ since if we were to write the $s_r$ for $n=k+1$ the for every $r$ there will be terms that contain $\tan(A_{k+1})$ and others that don't.

Answer (score 1):

Ya your approach is fully correct. One more approach could be-

$ \tan (A+B)=\dfrac{tanA+tanB}{1-\tan A \tan B} $

$ \tan (A+B+C)= \dfrac{\tan A+\tan B + \tan C-\tan A \tan B \tan C}{1-\tan A \tan B-tanB \tan C-\tan C\tan A} $

The RHS simplifies to

$$ \frac{S_1-S_3}{1-S_2} $$

Thus $\tan(A_1+A_2+A_3+..........+A_n)$ can be reduced to $\dfrac{s_1-s_3+s_5+......}{1-s_2+s_4+........}$